# extra line in tab host

Tags: android

I'm really really stuck the following problem.
I used FrameLayout inside LinearLayout  and then through code i added linearlayout to this FrameLayout but it produce an extra space. I have given the screen shot below. 
[image]

I part marked as white is the problem. i need to remove this.
My FrameLayout

```
<TabHost
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp">
        </TabWidget>
        <FrameLayout
            tyle="@style/tabhost"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"             
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </TabHost>
```

This is the linearLayout i added this FrameLayout

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Thank you

Comment: Maybe it'll be helpful if you also add the code where you add FrameLayout in the LinearLayout.

Comment: Sorry for that. Now i added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are trying to remove the fading bar on Tabhost,
If so refer this [Delete fading bar on Tabhost](http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/delete-fading-bar-on-tabhost-t14393.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting padding and margins of your view to 0.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Its not working. I have tried this already.:(