# Android -- How to remove that little extra padding when using a ListView with custom background?

Tags: android, padding, android-framelayout

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="#EAEAEA">

  <ListView  
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#464C59"         
        android:divider="#A4C539"
        android:dividerHeight="1px">
   </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home_bottom_bar"
        android:src="@drawable/bottombar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

The goal is to have some sort of advertising bar at the bottom of the activity (which contains a list of items). It works ok, except for one thing! There is some sort of extra space just under the bar (it's very small but it's noticeable enough). By the way, all the paddings are set to 0 so where does this space come from?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

After investigating the issue, it turns out that the custom background (`#EAEAEA`) is causing this extra space. Still don't know how to fix this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mention that it is a small extra space, it may be the tiny gradient at the top and bottom. Created by ListView, when it is made scrollable.

You may read about [ListView Backgrounds](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html), this should give you the idea on how to fix it, if it is caused by this special gradient.

This gradient line can apparently also be removed: [extra line in tab host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004889/extra-line-in-tab-host/5005848#5005848)

Comment: You are right it is apparently caused by the background (when I disable my custom background, the extra space disappears). However, I still don't know how to fix this. I have already set the cacheColorHint to `#000000` before.

Comment: Just added link to removal-solution

Comment: @Amokrane did your work it out? I tried, and was able to remove the extra space on one of mine (alas very simple) ListViews... did you give it a try?

Comment: setting padding to 0 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the merge tag since every activitys base layout is a FrameLayout.
(This may cause the padding. Im not 100% sure on this one though)
[Look here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html).

Comment: I think it has more to do with the background. When I remove the custom background, the space disappears. Merge will just optimize my view but won't change anything. Thanks though!

Comment: Mh that sounds weird. Just to clearify this: Did you try to set padding/margin to 0dp explicitly? (opposed to "if i dont note it, it's 0dp"). This may not be standard, but I had a 9-patch once with a similar issue. Explicitly stating the 0dps fixed that.